# Picture metadata is lost after using CameraRoll.save

Tags: ios, react-native, metadata, react-native-camera, camera-roll

I am using RNCamera to take pictures and write metadata in it , the only problem is that RNCamera saves the pictures in the app cache . so i used react-native-community/cameraroll library to save the taken picture to the cameraRoll ,
the main problem here is that the saved picture in cameraRoll is missing the metadata that was written with RNCamera .
is there a work around this ? am i missing an option in camreaRoll.save ?
below is my code

```
    export const startShootPhoto = async sensorState => {
     const camera = await getCameraRef();
        if (camera) {
         const location = {
         GPSLongitude: get("longitude", sensorState),
         GPSLatitude: get("altitude", sensorState),
         GPSAltitude: get("altitude", sensorState)
        };
     const options = {
      quality: 0.5,
      base64: true,
      exif: true,
      writeExif: location
     };

     const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options);
     await CameraRoll.save(get("uri", data), {
      type: "photo",
      album: "test"
     });
    }
  };
```